# how to send facebook button current href

Tags: php, javascript, facebook, href

```
<iframe src="http://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=<?php echo 'http://domainame.com/'.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'?'.$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];?>&amp;layout=button_count&amp;show_faces=false&amp;width=120&amp;action=recommend&amp;font=verdana&amp;colorscheme=light&amp;height=21"
 scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:120px; height:21px;" allowTransparency="true"></iframe>
```

But if i'm on http://domainame.com/?bla it prints http://domainame.com//index.php?bla

if i could just send this.href but i don't know how to insert js in-line here,

help?

With your help we got working:

```
<iframe src="http://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=<?php echo str_replace("index.php","",'http://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']); ?>&amp;layout=button_count&amp;show_faces=true&amp;width=150&amp;action=recommend&amp;font&amp;colorscheme=light&amp;height=21" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:120px; height:21px;" allowTransparency="true"></iframe>
```

can get better?

Comment: can i do it inline? or i'm going to have to do it on $(document).ready ?

Comment: It can be done inline, just posted an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the following as a value for `href`:

```php
<?php echo rawurlencode('http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']); ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this: `<?php echo rawurlencode('http://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']); ?>`

(BTW, you should **never** use `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']` for *anything* of this sort, due to injection vulnerabilities. [Read this](http://www.html-form-guide.com/php-form/php-form-action-self.html) for details.)

Comment: should this be working for every single URL i may use? even with modrewrite?

Comment: thaks for your time :) it's same solution @Marcel suggested ;)

Answer (score -1):

I image that the page is named `index.php` and your server sets `index.php` as the default page, which would mean `http://domainame.com//index.php?bla` is interchangeable as a page reference to `http://domainame.com/?bla`.

Comment: yes but that is not the answer to how to send this.href to the facebook's iframe? thanks though!